# How do I store an array of strings into another array of strings?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, shuffle

I'm trying to store my old array of struct type that holds first names of people into a new string array that has been downsized so I can then shuffle it round in another method.

```
string[] newStringArray = new string[10]

for (int i = 0; i < oldStringArray.Length; i++)
{    
    newStringArray = oldStringArray[i].firstName;//Cannot convert type 'string to 'string[]'
}

foreach (string value in newStringArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, you are defining a new array with ten elements but then enumerating over all the old elements. Do you want newStringArray to contain the first ten firstnames of oldStringArray?

Comment: Yes I do want my newStringArray to contain the first ten names of oldStringArray.

Comment: You set the whole array, just use the indexer `newStringArray[i] = oldStringArray[i].firstName;`

Comment: Change your loop condition from i < oldStringArray.Length to (i < oldStringArray.Length && i < newStringArray.Length)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the index accessor:

```
string[] newStringArray = new string[10];
for (int i = 0; i < oldStringArray.Length && i < newStringArray.Length; i++)
{
    newStringArray[i] = oldStringArray[i].firstName;
    //             ^
}
```

Comment: If oldStringArray contains more than 10 elements you would then get an index out of bounds exception when accessing newStringArray[10]

Answer (score 3):

You can project your `FirstName` properties using [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx), and then materialize them into a new array using [`Enumerable.ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
string[] firstNames = oldStringArray.Select(x => x.FirstName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the new array with the same size as the old one.

```
string[] newStringArray = new string[oldStringArray.Length];
```

Then use the indexer to set the elements of the new array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < oldStringArray.Length; i++)
{    
    newStringArray[i] = oldStringArray[i].firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the first ten firstnames then use

```
var firstTenFirstNames = oldStringArray.Select(x => x.FirstName).Take(10).ToArray()
```